# Having issues with removing preceding zeroes and characters after special characters from a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to remove alphabets, space from left, right and in between, preceding zeros, and all the characters after special characters(comma,semicolon, backslash, forward slash)

I have a column that contains value like the below :

```
051 765 999
MK00564123
KJ786453425/9
432563542/3
096745632
53452BMG441,8
```

I am trying to remove alphabets and space from left and right from the value for those values containing alphabets in the value and also preceding 0.

**Expected Output:**

```
51765999
564123
96745632
```

Also, I am trying to remove everything after a special character in the column(comma,semicolon, backslash, forward slash):

**Expected Output:**

```
786453425
432563542
53452441
```

**Final Output:**

```
51765999
564123
96745632
786453425
432563542
53452441
```

I have created the fiddle but not getting the expected output as shown below:

[image]

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b383/1123

Can someone please help me to identify what is the issue and how can I get the expected output?

Comment: version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith 2017 or above

Comment: Write a udf for this and call it in every query. Or better... **Fix the data one time**

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER version 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetCleanedAlphaNumeric (@alphanumeric VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT SUBSTRING(cleaned, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', cleaned + 'x'), 8000) AS Final
       FROM   (VALUES (SUBSTRING(@alphanumeric, 1, PATINDEX('%[,;\/]%', @alphanumeric + ';') - 1))) ca1(prefix)
              CROSS APPLY (VALUES ( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(prefix, ' ', ''), 'a', '')
                                    , 'b', ''), 'c', ''), 'd', ''), 'e', ''), 'f', '')
                                    , 'g', ''), 'h', ''), 'i', ''), 'j', ''), 'k', '')
                                    , 'l', ''), 'm', ''), 'n', ''), 'o', ''), 'p', '')
                                    , 'q', ''), 'r', ''), 's', ''), 't', ''), 'u', '')
                                    , 'v', ''), 'w', ''), 'x', ''), 'y', ''), 'z', '') )) ca2(cleaned))
```

and then

```
SELECT alphanumeric,
       Final
FROM   temp
CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_GetCleanedAlphaNumeric(alphanumeric)
```

- First extract the substring before any `,;\/` (if present)
- Then strip out any letters or spaces (can be made much more concise on later versions with `TRANSLATE` function as in edit history)
- Then remove leading zeroes

([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P-4M6trC))

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Is it a good idea to wrap it in a function?

Comment: If you do use a function I'd use an inline TVF rather than a scalar one. Scalar functions can be inlined in recent versions but there have been a lot of teething issues with that

Comment: That TVF will return varchar right?

Comment: It will return a table with a single row and single column, the column will be varchar https://dbfiddle.uk/nYbeXzYd

Comment: I am getting "Translate" is not a built in function. Any alternative to Translate please?

Comment: It exists in 2017 as stated - what version are you actually using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253905/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-martin-smith).

Comment: SQL Server Version is 2016. I got confused with studio version

Comment: I have created a new question if you can please help me with it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382908/how-to-remove-alphabets-preceding-zeroes-and-characters-after-special-character

Comment: The answer was already edited to work in 2016

Answer (score 1):

To trim leading zeroes from a numeric string:

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('00123', '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') -- returns '123'
```

Change your return to:

```
RETURN REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2fc34/1).

This works by changing all `0` to a space, left trimming, then changing all space back to `0`.

---

Of course if SQL Server ever gets around to supporting `REGEXP_REPLACE()` it would be trivial:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('00123', '^0+', '') -- would return '123'
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.  There is issue with inputs 53452BMG441,8 and 432563542/3. Its not matching the expected output

Comment: What are the expected outputs exactly?

Comment: Its in the "ExpectedOutput"

Comment: In SQL Server 2022 this is already trivial `SELECT LTRIM ( '000123' , '0' )` - not available in 2017 though

Answer (score 1):

This function can be easily inlined.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
declare @i bigint
set @strAlphaNumeric = replace(TRANSLATE(@strAlphaNumeric, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz /\,;', replicate('a', 27)+replicate(';',4)),'a','')
set @i=charindex(';',@strAlphaNumeric)
if @i>0
   set @strAlphaNumeric = left(@strAlphaNumeric,@i-1)
RETURN replace(LTRIM(replace(ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
END
```

Comment: Record count 0. It is not returning any records. Can you please try in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use `PATINDEX` to find the position of the first non-alphanumeric or space character, and get the `LEFT` most characters up to that point.

Then I use a helper function I wrote which replaces characters that fit a certain pattern with another character. As you are on SQL Server 2016, then you'll need to use the XML version of it, as `STRING_AGG` was added in 2017. (note that the helper function also uses a tally helper function, as `GENERATE_SERIES` was added in 2022).

Finally I convert the value to a `bigint` to trim leading zeroes.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@LastNumber bigint, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    --Copyright Thom A (https://larnu.uk) under CC-by-SA
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
          AND @LastNumber IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@LastNumber,0))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally T;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[PatternCharacterReplace_XML] (@String varchar(8000), @Pattern varchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter varchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    --Copyright Thom A (https://larnu.uk) under CC-by-SA
    SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END
            FROM fn.Tally(CONVERT(int,LEN(@String)),1) T
                 CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C)
            ORDER BY T.I
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(8000)') AS ReplacedString;
GO
SELECT V.YourString,
       PI.I,
       LEFT(V.YourString,PI.I),
       TRY_CONVERT(bigint,PCRX.ReplacedString)
FROM (VALUES('051 765 999'),
            ('MK00564123'),
            ('KJ786453425/9'),
            ('432563542/3'),
            ('096745632'),
            ('53452BMG441,8'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9 A-Z]%',V.YourString),0)-1,LEN(V.YourString))))PI(I)
     CROSS APPLY fn.PatternCharacterReplace_XML(LEFT(V.YourString,PI.I),'[^0-9]','') PCRX;
```

This'll certainly work on versions as old as SQL Server 2012 for strings where the numbers to return are 18 numbers or less.

If the numerical value would be greater than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 then you could use `PATINDEX` and `STUFF` to remove the leading `0` characters.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/374a4/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
DECLARE @intSpecial INT
SET @intSpecial = PATINDEX('%[.,+*?^$(){}\\/]%', @strAlphanumeric)
IF @intSpecial > 0
BEGIN
   SET @strAlphaNumeric = SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric,1,@intSpecial)
END

SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(
@strAlphaNumeric
  , '0', ' ')),' ', '0'),0)
END
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
create table temp
(
    alphanumeric varchar(100)
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/374a4/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
insert into temp
(alphanumeric)
values
('051 765 999'),
('MK00564123'),
('KJ786453425/9'),
('432563542/3'),
('096745632'),
('53452BMG441,8')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/374a4/1/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT alphanumeric,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(alphanumeric) 
from temp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/374a4/1/2)**:

```
|  alphanumeric |           |
|---------------|-----------|
|   051 765 999 |  51765999 |
|    MK00564123 |    564123 |
| KJ786453425/9 | 786453425 |
|   432563542/3 | 432563542 |
|     096745632 |  96745632 |
| 53452BMG441,8 |  53452441 |
```

Comment: I must admit, a `WHILE` within a multi-line scalar function may well not be the most "performant" solution.

Comment: All string functions are not perfomant, so the loop version will not be slower as the comparison of 26 chatcters of the accepted snswer

Comment: *"All string functions are not perfomant"* Citation needed.

Comment: Also I and many other delopers wanted a reg replace from Microsoft which was us still denied

Comment: But such a function wouldn't be performant by your claims, @nbk . ;) (This comment is not to say that regex support natively in SQL Server would be unwelcome.)

Comment: Also the results aren't correct here. The OP doesn't want characters *after* a special character (excluding space). So `53452BMG441,8`  and `KJ786453425/9` should return `53452441` and `786453425` respectively (your results have the trailing `8` and `9` still in the value).

Comment: thta eseasily fixed, see changes

Answer (score 1):

Here You can use this function which uses `PATINDEX`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveAlphabets
(
    @input          VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN

    declare
    @match_pattern  VARCHAR(MAX) = '%[a-z ]%',
    @stop_pattern  VARCHAR(MAX) = '%[.,/]%',
    @replace_value  VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @match_ix   INT,
    @input_copy          VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @input_copy = @input

    SET @match_ix = PATINDEX(@stop_pattern, @input_copy);
    IF @match_ix > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @input_copy = SUBSTRING(@input_copy, 1, @match_ix - 1)
    END

    SET @match_ix = PATINDEX(@match_pattern, @input_copy);
    
    WHILE @match_ix > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @input_copy = REPLACE(@input_copy, SUBSTRING(@input_copy, @match_ix, 1), @replace_value);
        SET @match_ix = PATINDEX(@match_pattern, @input_copy);
    END


    RETURN @input_copy;

END
```

And this is a test.

```
select dbo.RemoveAlphabets(col1)
from (
    VALUES  (N'051 765 999')
    ,   (N'MK00564123')
    ,   (N'KJ786453425/9')
    ,   (N'432563542/3')
    ,   (N'096745632')
    ,   (N'53452BMG441,8')
) t (col1)
```